# Why all comments have no effect of application.css.scss and application.js in rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, comments

I have a weird confusion, when I use application.js in rails like that:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

and use application.css.scss like that:

```
/*

 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I think // is a comment in JS file and /* */ is also a comment in CSS file, I didn't think too much and just use before, but for now I wanna know why all comments in JS and CSS file have no effects in rails?

Comment: I have no idea about Ruby, but quick google search brought `<%#  %>` as comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both `//` and `/* */` are comments for `js` and `css` files respectively, but `//=` and `*=` are directives used by `sprockets`, from the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sstephenson/sprockets/Sprockets/DirectiveProcessor):

> The `DirectiveProcessor` is responsible for parsing and evaluating
>   directive comments in a source file.
>
> A directive comment starts with a comment prefix, followed by an “=”,
>   then the directive name, then any arguments.
>
> ```
> // JavaScript
> //= require "foo"
>
> # CoffeeScript
> #= require "bar"
>
> /* CSS
>  *= require "baz"
>  */
> ```

So `js` or `.css` files will treat `//=` and `*=` as comments, but `sprockets` will read those directives to load the required files into the rails asset pipeline.

Check also the [sprockets guides](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/end_user_asset_generation.md) for more detailed information.